# Get current script location in Nu shell

Tags: shell, nushell

In bash you can use `$0` variable to get the location of the current script. How I do the same in Nu? `echo $nu` doesn't seem to have anything I can use.

Comment: Try echo(script) or 

echo $pwd 
ls

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As long as you know the name of the file, you can do:

```
$env.FILE_PWD | path join filename
```

This will only work if you are executing the file as a script, not sourcing it.

Comment: It's possible this value might change so worth following https://github.com/nushell/nushell/issues/7692

Comment: @JacobWang Won't change. The issue has been closed.

Comment: Follow up question: how to retrieve the path of sourced file from within the sourced file? https://stackoverflow.com/q/78058240/851118

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to do this yet. I was playing with `history | last` but it's one off, as you'd expect.

Answer (score -1):

> ($nu.config-path | path dirname )

Comment: While this works for getting the path to the config file, it doesn't work in general for any given script regardless of its location.