# Get current sourced script location in Nu shell

Tags: shell, nushell

In a script, we can use `$env.FILE_PWD` to get the script's location. However, this approach failed for sourced file, e.g.

`main.nu`:

```
source ./lib/func.nu

echo $"Script file:  ($env.FILE_PWD)"
echo $"Sourced file: (get-sourced-file)"
```

`./lib/func.nu`:

```
export def get-sourced-file [] {
  # this will return path of main.nu
  # Is there command/env to retrieve path of func.nu?
  $env.FILE_PWD
}
```

Output:

```bash
$ nu main.nu
Script file:  /tmp/test
Sourced file: /tmp/test
```

Q: How to retrieve the sourced file path of `/tmp/test/lib` from within the `lib/func.nu`?

Comment: As only static paths can be `source`d (because of the [strict parse-evaluation separation](https://www.nushell.sh/book/how_nushell_code_gets_run.html)), just expand the static path directly: `echo $"Sourced file: ('./lib' | path expand)"`. Or use `const` to manage its value in a single place: `const p = './lib'; source $"($p)/func.nu"; …; echo $"Sourced file: ($p | path expand)"`

Comment: Yup, that's for getting sourced file path from the sourcing file (`main.nu` in this case). But how about getting the filepath of `./lib/func.nu` from within `./lib/func.nu`? The use case is for `func.nu` to retrieve other files relative to itself.

Comment: What does "retrieve" mean? As said, you cannot source dynamic paths because the evaluation of such a dynamic path happens only after all the parsing, which includes the opening and parsing of any sourced content. Nu is a compiled language after all. You'd need to read other files and `eval` them to circumvent this.

Comment: my specific use case is using `lib/func.nu` as a wrapper for `lib/func.vbs` to invoke Windows COM object (Excel). Within `lib/func.nu`, I'll call `func.vbs` like `cscript full/path/to/func.vbs`. My problem is getting `full/path/to/func.vbs` from within `func.nu`.


I don't want to polute `main.nu` with details on how `func.nu` achieve its function.

Comment: Again, this path is known at compile time (when the sources are collected and parsed), not at run time (when any code is evaluated and executed). But your `main.nu` is already "polluted" with that path (in the `source` line), so just make it available (e.g. using `const`), then use that variable inside `func.nu`.

Answer (score 0):

Nu is a compiled language, strictly separating the parsing of source code from its evaluation (see [How Nushell Code Gets Run](https://www.nushell.sh/book/how_nushell_code_gets_run.html)). Therefore, this path is known at compile time (when the sources are collected and parsed), but not at run time (when any code is evaluated and executed). But your `main.nu` already contains the path relative to its own location, so just make this static string available, e.g. using `const`, to be used later in a dynamic context where it can be expanded, e.g. using `path expand`:

```bash
# ./main.nu

const libpath = './lib'
source $"($libpath)/func.nu"

# unchanged rest of the file:
echo $"Script file:  ($env.FILE_PWD)"
echo $"Sourced file: (get-sourced-file)"
```

```bash
# ./lib/func.nu

export def get-sourced-file [] {
  $libpath | path expand
}
```

Output:

```
$ nu main.nu
Script file:  /tmp/test
Sourced file: /tmp/test/lib
```